# combobox ownerdrawfixed delete item c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox with the DrawMode in OwnerDrawFixed, when I delete the elements the last gate remains written in the textbox, how can I delete it? Currently I use this code to delete the elements and not to show the last one

```
public void RemoveCurrentItem()
{
   if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
   {                
      comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
      comboBox1.Text = null;
   }       
}
```

Code Draw:

```
if (((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).Items.Count != 0)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            string text = ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
            Brush brush;
            if (e.Index == 0)
                brush = Brushes.Red;
            else
                brush = Brushes.Black;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        }
```

Comment: This code works fine here. What are: 'Gate', 'TextBox', 'last one'? Why do you think ownerdrawing has anything to do with it? __If__ you have a good reason to think so you should show the drawing code!

Comment: @TaW the last element remains written in the combobox, even after being deleted
Code Draw:
 if (((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).Items.Count != 0)
            {
                e.DrawBackground();
                string text = ((System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString();
                Brush brush;
                if (e.Index == 0)
                    brush = Brushes.Red;
                else
                    brush = Brushes.Black;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
            }

Comment: Do you mean text you added to the textbox portion? Well this is not part of the items; to get rid of it simply move the comboBox1.Text = null; line out of the if block!

Comment: @TaW i have add code to the question!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the textbox portion of the `ComboBox` and text that was **just entered there** the effect really happens and has nothing to do with either owner-drawing the control or with how many items are left.

The `if` block only executes if there is a list element and if there isn't the line that clears the text area is not executed.

This will always clear the text portion:

```
public void RemoveCurrentItem()
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
    comboBox1.Text = null;
}
```

Comment: OK perfect. now if I can always ask you something else, why after erasing everything the combobox doesn't resize? That is, it always takes the drop as if it had tot elements

Comment: It seems to revert to the original number of items when all items are gone. Not even changing comboBox1.MaxDropDownItems seems to help. Weird.. But you can enforce it like this `comboBox1.DropDownHeight = comboBox1.Items.Count * comboBox1.ItemHeight + 1;` You will have to do this each time you change the number of items!